# Check if Django url is present or a part of it is present?

Tags: django

The problem is simple. If I want to check if the url like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/discussions
```

is active, I will do,

```
{% url 'discussions:index' as discussions %}
<li class="nav-item {% if request.get_full_path == discussions %}active{% endif %}">
     <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'discussions:index' %}">Discussions </a>
</li>
```

But I want to make the same nav bar link active for this url too:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/discussions/Q15

But I don't have the question id (Q15) in navbar template. How should I compare it so that this becomes active (true condition) for all the urls of type:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/discussions/anything/anything2

urls.py

```
app_name = 'discussions'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<question_id>Q[0-9]+)$', views.question, name='question'),
url(r'^ask/', views.ask, name='ask'),
url(r'^answer/(?P<question_id>Q[0-9]+)$', views.answer, name='answer'),
url(r'^delete/(?P<id>[AQ][0-9]+)', views.delete, name='delete'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<id>[AQ][0-9]+)', views.edit, name='edit'),
url(r'^confirm/(?P<id>[AQ][0-9]+)', views.confirm, name='confirm'),
url(r'^vote/', views.vote, name='vote'), 
}
```

I want it to be true for all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% if discussions in request.get_full_path %}active{% endif %}
```

Hope it helps!